# Replacing all data in a column by using a character object

Tags: r

I have column of discrete variables (levels) although they are in many different languages, including English.

```
> head(euregs$focus)
[1] Arable farming                                                           
[2] Arable farming, Livestock farming, Services                              
[3] Horticulture, On-farm Product processing and marketing, Economics        
[4] Livestock farming, Horticulture, On-farm Product processing and marketing
[5] Arable farming, Livestock farming, Economics                             
[6] Other                                                                    
95 Levels:  Ã…Â¾ivinoreja, ekonomika ... vrtnarstvo, predelava in prodaja na domu, ekonomika
```

My goal is to replace all of these data with the English translations. I have two objects, a list of all 95 levels of the mixed language column and an English translation of these levels:

```
> str(foclevs)
 chr [1:95] "" "Ã…Â¾ivinoreja, ekonomika" "Ã…Â¾ivinoreja, ekonomika, administracija in finance" ...
> str(engfocus)
 chr [1:95] "" "Livestock farming, Economics" "Livestock farming, Economics, Administration and Finances" ...
```

How can I use these objects to replace all of the values in the mixed language column?

Comment: `factor(foclevs,labels=engfocus)`

Comment: this made the translations, thanks.  But the result is still too short, the repeat observations are not being transferred `euregs$engfocus <- factor(foclevs, labels=engfocus)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, engfocus, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  : 
  replacement has 95 rows, data has 163`

Comment: Two options, either you make the engfocus vector as long as the data, so manually match the repeats or use a different approach with matching to deal with this automatically. See for ex. `match()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple iteration can do the trick. I would do:

```
translated_to_english <- sapply(seq_along(foclevs), function(x) engfocs[x])
```

Comment: This is returning an error that I unfortunately don't understand `> engtranslate <- sapply(seq_len(foclevs), function(x) engfocus[x])
Error in seq_len(foclevs) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`

Comment: okay, lets debug. what is the `class` of engfocus and foclevs ?

Comment: both are character.  changing to factor with `as.factor` then re-running your code results in a different error `translated_to_english <- sapply(seq_len(foclevs), function(x) engfocus[x])
Warning message:
In seq_len(foclevs) : first element used of 'length.out' argument`

Comment: @AdamC sorry, I was using `seq_len` before which was wrong, I've updated the answer.

Comment: your code produced a translation of all of the levels, then collapsed them based on values equal to eachother. However, the same challenge remains. All 163 rows of `euregs$focus` need to be translated.  By this point I have already made the translations by `gsub` but it was a major pain.  all of the special characters killed me.